# How to authorize into a downstream API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization

We use OAuth 2.0 for authorization.

A server side web app first sends client credentials to an authorization server and obtains a JWT token. It then sends a request to API-1. API-1 needs to send a request of its own to API-2.

Is it possible to use the same JWT that API-1 already has received from client, to authorize in API-2?

If not, what authorization method can be used in this scenario?

From the documentation that I have read it appears impossible to reuse the same JWT, but I am also not sure what would be the correct approach to use here.

Comment: Why is it impossible? Nothing is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access tokens are designed to be used by multiple APIs, so forwarding the token is a good default action. This flows the user identity and other token claims in a verifiable and auditable way. Each API then validates the JWT before allowing the request.

Token forwarding is usually combined with scopes and audience checks though, to set boundaries. Eg the token might have these values for a `sales` business area:

```
aud: api.mycompany.com
scope: openid sales
```

Each API must check for its required audience and scopes. These can be designed in various ways, eg different API operations can require different scopes if needed. If the above token was sent to a `finance` API that required a different scope, it would be rejected with a 403 error.

When crossing trust boundaries, token forwarding is usually avoided, eg if there are concerns about the upstream API misusing the token. In such cases some kind of [token exchange](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8693.html) may be used, which continues to flow the identity, though perhaps with reduced permissions.